# Determine limits of operation frequency in simulator - Vivado

Tags: fpga, vivado

Is there any way to check maximal frequency of my design in Vivado?

I kind of get the result by running Post Synthesis Timing Simulation. I start of by setting my clock period at certain value and decrease it. Once my design doesn't do what it's supposed to do, I increase my clock period and determine maximal frequency as 1/clock_period.

I'm new to using Vivado so I don't even know if there is a possibility to check max frequency in some report. There is this option in Quartus, so I assume Vivado has it as well. I just don't know where to find it.

Can anyone help me with this? Thanks

Comment: It's reported for each clock during static timing analysis, same as in Quartus.

Comment: Vivado has more comprehensive userguides and video tutorials than Quartus. You should find your answer in any of them. For eg: there is a guide called "constraints".

Answer (score 0):

You don't normally bother, and not just because post-synthesis simulation is so slow.

The fact that it is post-synthesis simulation implies that you have already run synthesis, which will already give you a timing summary according to your timing constraints - this already includes a maximum achievable clock frequency for the device and conditions you specified.

Place and route ("implementation") will deliver a slightly different set of figures in the final timing summary : these are the ones you should rely on.